# How to get started with react-native-bootsplash

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to make a splash screen using react-native-bootsplash. I have followed the instructions on npm and the library is installed properly but I am not able to understand how to use it. Can someone give me an example or a small code snippet that I can write in App.js and get started. A basic example would do fine.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I integrated with RN `0.62.2`:

**Step 1:** Add the package to react-native project

```
yarn add react-native-bootsplash
```

**Step 2:** Generate assets for bootscreen.

```
yarn generate-bootsplash
...
yarn run v1.19.0
$ /Users/sresu/personal/startups/chill/code/chill-app-rn/node_modules/.bin/generate-bootsplash
✔ The path to the root of your React Native project … .
✔ The path to your static assets directory … assets
✔ Your original icon file … assets/bootsplash_logo_original.png
✔ The bootsplash background color (in hexadecimal) … #FFF
✔ The desired icon width (in dp - we recommend approximately ~100) … 100
✔ Are you sure? All the existing bootsplash images will be overwritten! … yes
  Looking good! Generating files…
✨  android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/bootsplash_logo.png (100x100)
✨  android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/bootsplash_logo.png (150x150)
✨  android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/bootsplash_logo.png (300x300)
✨  ios/chill/Images.xcassets/BootSplashLogo.imageset/bootsplash_logo@2x.png (200x200)
✨  ios/chill/Images.xcassets/BootSplashLogo.imageset/bootsplash_logo@3x.png (300x300)
✨  assets/bootsplash_logo.png (100x100)
✨  assets/bootsplash_logo@1,5x.png (150x150)
✨  assets/bootsplash_logo@2x.png (200x200)
✨  assets/bootsplash_logo@3x.png (300x300)
✨  assets/bootsplash_logo@4x.png (400x400)
✨  android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/bootsplash_logo.png (400x400)
✨  ios/chill/Images.xcassets/BootSplashLogo.imageset/bootsplash_logo.png (100x100)
✨  android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/bootsplash_logo.png (200x200)
✨  ios/chill/BootSplash.storyboard
✨  android/app/src/main/res/drawable/bootsplash.xml
✨  android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml
✅  Done! Thanks for using react-native-bootsplash.
✨  Done in 10.86s.
```

**Step 3:** Update this file -> `android/app/src/main/java/com/chill/MainActivity.java`

```
import com.zoontek.rnbootsplash.RNBootSplash; //<- add this import statement

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return ....
  }

  // Add this for splash screen
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RNBootSplash.init(R.drawable.bootsplash, MainActivity.this); // <- display the generated bootsplash.xml drawable over our MainActivity
  }
}
```

**Step 4:** Modify `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Add the following lines -->
    <!-- BootTheme should inherit from AppTheme -->
    <style name="BootTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- set the generated bootsplash.xml drawable as activity background -->
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bootsplash</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Make sure you should have this file - `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/bootsplash.xml`, this is generated from Step 2.

**Step 5:** Modify `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
...
<application
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                android:exported="true">
            <!--        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">-->
        </activity>
        <!-- add the following lines (use the theme you created at step 3) -->
        <activity
                android:name="com.zoontek.rnbootsplash.RNBootSplashActivity"
                android:theme="@style/BootTheme"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="chill" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                        android:host="chill.com"
                        android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                        android:host="chill.com"
                        android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

    </application>
...
```

**Last step:** Hide splash screen when app is ready

```
class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    componentDidMount() {
        RNBootSplash.hide({duration: 250}); // fade
...
```

Official docs: https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can we show the bigger size picture on android devices ?

Comment: yarn generate-bootsplash Command "generate-bootsplash" not found.

Comment: @RahulShakya try this `npx react-native generate-bootsplash ./assets/bootsplash_logo_original.png --background-color=ECF1FF --logo-width=200 --assets-path=./assets
`

Comment: @0case Your solution works, but a few modifications are needed. Replace `--background-color` with `--background` and `--assets-path` with `--assets-output`

Answer (score 0):

npx react-native generate-bootsplash ./assets/bootsplash_logo_original.png --background --logo-width=200 --assets-output=./assets

error Option "--license-key" is missing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).